# Programmatically Set Proxy Address, Port, Username, Password

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

Hi I need to set proxy address of IE programmatically

Earlier I used to use this [RedTomahawk.TORActivator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Change_IE7_Proxy_Setting.aspx)
but it doesnot gives an option to set those proxies which requires username and password.

How can we set those proxies which needs username and passwords

Please provide examples like

`void Setproxy(string ip,string port,string uname,string pwd)
{
   ///Code here
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could P/Invoke the [WinHttpSetDefaultProxyConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384113.aspx) function.

---

UPDATE:

Including example as requested:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO
{
    public AccessType AccessType;
    public string Proxy;
    public string Bypass;
}

public enum AccessType
{
    DefaultProxy = 0,
    NamedProxy = 3,
    NoProxy = 1
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("winhttp.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinHttpSetDefaultProxyConfiguration(ref WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO config);

    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO();
        config.AccessType = AccessType.NamedProxy;
        config.Proxy = "http://proxy.yourcompany.com:8080";
        config.Bypass = "intranet.com";

        var result = WinHttpSetDefaultProxyConfiguration(ref config);
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully modified proxy settings");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide an example :- void setproxy(string proxy,string port,string username,string password){  ///code here   }

Comment: - Hi sir, I am actually using a WatIN IE for doing some requests. what happens is: after few requests my ip is being blocked. at that time I wish to change my ip address( I have some valid proxy adresses in the format xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx:username:password). Using RedTomahawk.TORActivator I was able to set ip:port easily but now the proxy list I have asks for username password also. my question is how to set these username,passwords programatically also. Please help

Comment: What type of authentication does your proxy use? If it is basic authentication you could try setting it like this: `http://username:password@yourproxy.com:8080`. If it is integrated Windows Authentication it will depend on the user running your program.

Comment: Thank yoy very much Sir Darin Dimitrov for helping me. I understood that probably there is no direct way of setting the username password directly. please see this link for my actual problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276044/how-to-handle-windows-security-alert-dialog-box-using-watin-ie and please help

Comment: @DarinDimitrov the code doesn't work. It returns "true" but nothing changed with the proxy settings. Could you help please?

Comment: @Dark_Knight Yes, it changes default proxy setting only for WinHTTP. According to the [documantation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384069.aspx#_uninstall) this sets registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\WinHttpSettings`. But IE (and other browsers) uses `DefaultConnectionSettings` in same registry key. Warning: 32b browsers uses Wow6432Node branch.